# Could not retrieve the required option 'entityID' on very basic configuration with openIdP

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I receive this error while test the authentication in the admin panel of ssPhp or while open federation tab.

`Caused by: SimpleSAML\Assert\AssertionFailedException: authsources['sp-test']: Could not retrieve the required option 'entityID'.`

Im trying to set up a `simplesamlphp 2.0.3` `SP` on `PHP 8.1.17`. I didnt configure Apache alias and just set in `config.php` the `baseurlpath` to `mydomain.com/simplesamlphp/public/`.  I've created an account on openIdP and then finaly set in

`authsources.php`

```
'sp-test' => array(
  'saml:SP',
  'entityId' => 'https://openidp.feide.no',
  'idp' => 'https://openidp.feide.no',
),
```

and in
`saml20-idp-remote.php`

```
 $metadata['https://openidp.feide.no'] = array (
    'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
    'entityid' => 'https://openidp.feide.no',
    'SingleSignOnService' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        'Location' => 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
      ),
    ),
    'SingleLogoutService' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        'Location' => 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
      ),
    ),
    'certData' => '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',
    'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',
    'contacts' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'emailAddress' => 'moria-drift@uninett.no',
        'contactType' => 'technical',
        'givenName' => 'OpenIdP',
        'surName' => 'support',
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Its really basic setup so I dont understand whats wrong. The admin menu has all needed modules and php-extensions.

Comment: `'entityID'` is not `'entityId'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic case... a hard-to spot typo in the authsource array

```
'sp-test' => array(
  'saml:SP',
  'entityId' => 'https://openidp.feide.no',
  'idp' => 'https://openidp.feide.no',
),
```

Error message says `authsources['sp-test']: Could not retrieve the required option 'entityID'`, indicating that the element int "sp-test" must be named `entityID`

Answer (score 1):

In the older version this could be left NULL, does it mean that **entityID** is now a required option?

Comment: It would appear not! And must be a valid URL which the metadata equivalent didn't need to be. Not sure if the metadata version now has to be. tbc!